# Enable php5 on a single directory on an ISS server?

Tags: php, iis

On Apache server's I can create a .htaccess file with the following code.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Is there something similar that I can do for a windows server or does php5 need to be enabled site wide?

Answer (score 0):

PHP can be disabled on an individual site via the Handler Mappings for a given site.  Information on setting up the handler mapping can be found [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-7/#Configure_handler_mapping), but if it is already enabled on a site, you only have to disable it on the Handler Mapping settings.

You may also want to have a look at the [PHP Manaager for IIS](http://phpmanager.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex.